# In react datatables.net-bs4, how to bind the edit button with dynamic data in td

Tags: reactjs, datatables

In my react datatable, I want to add edit button  to each row of dynamic data.
In react datatable.net-bs4,
I can't bind button with data. I want to add edit button in each row of data.please solve thi problem kindly ...

View my error in photo that I upload [image: Object Object show instead of showing button]

_setDataInTable(list) {

```
    var table;
    if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#dataTables-category')) {
        table = $('#dataTables-category').dataTable();
        table.fnClearTable();
        table.fnDestroy();
        $('#dataTables-category').empty()
    }
    //if (list.length > 0) {
    var l = []
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        const data = list[i]
        const obj = {
            No: data.id,
            categoryNameByMM: data.categoryNameByMM,
            categoryNameByEg: data.categoryNameByEg,
            creationDate: data.creationDate,
            active: data.active,
            edit:

                <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#editModal">
                    <i className="fa fa-cogs"></i>&nbsp;Edit
                </button>

        }
        l.push(obj)
    }

    table = $("#dataTables-category").DataTable({
        data: l,
        columns: [
            { title: "No", data: "No" },
            { title: "Category Name in Myanmar", data: "categoryNameByMM" },
            { title: "Category Name in Myanmar", data: "categoryNameByEg" },
            { title: "Creation Date", data: "creationDate" },
            { title: "Active", data: "active" },
            { title: "Edit", data: "edit" }
        ],
        autofill: true,
        bLengthChange: false,
        bInfo: false,
        responsive: true,
        paging: false,
        buttons: true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
        ]

    });
}
```

render() {

```
    return (
        <div>

            <h1 className="page-header">Category Setup</h1>

            <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb20" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">
                <i className="fa fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add New
                </button>
            <div className="panel pagination-primary clearfix m-b-0">
                <div className="table-responsive" style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                    <table width="99%"
                        className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover responsive nowrap"
                        id="dataTables-category"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
```

)}

Comment: Hi you are solved above issue or not ?